# How to check what apps were installed on top on Windows 10 WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.3 version by comparing correct manifest file?

Tags: command-line, apt, apt-cache

How to check what apps were installed on top on Windows 10 WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.3 version by comparing correct manifest file?

Where to find correct manifest file with list of all WSL2 Ubuntu version?

How to use it to compare what apps were installed on top?

How to remove all apps that were installed on top of clean install?